# Maven Code Coverage Report for JUnit Test

Tags: java, maven, junit

I been looking at IntelliJ and I love the Code Coverage Report for JUnit Test but I would like to know if anyone is using anything or know of any plugs that can be used with Maven to build a report at test time of Code Coverage Report for JUnit Test

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Sonar plugin for maven](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/)

Run with `maven sonar:sonar`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example config that works well with [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

```
<!--no longer executed in test phase. Run cobertura:cobertura to generate -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
        <instrumentation>
            <ignores>
                <ignore>test.package.if.needed.later.*</ignore>
            </ignores>
            <excludes>
                <!-- eg.: -->
                <exclude>javax/**/*.class</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </instrumentation>
        <formats>
            <format>html</format>
            <format>xml</format>
        </formats>
        <check />
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks Anders but how can I tell it to run the test on only org.<myfirm> packages.. any how can I make jenkins fail if the test vol is low?  do you have twitter

Comment: Have a look at http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html - especially the `<check>` tag. You can use the `<ignore>` and `<exclude>` to leave out coverage checking on certain packages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) to see the code coverage for my unit tests. It works exactly as it should. It even allows you to merge multiple coverage tests instead of retesting everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Maven Cobertura Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/)