# Can i get code coverage of test from JUnit 5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, code-coverage

Is it possible to get code coverage for a test (lines of code which test  goes through) with JUnit 5 API? Or it's possible to get code coverage with IntelliJ Idea API? Code coverage info needs to be callable from code.

Thanks for help

Comment: I don't think it is something JUnit does. You need some external tool that would perform static code analysis.

Comment: With `intelliJ` next to the `Run` and `Debug` buttons, you have a `Run with coverage` button

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469661/junit-how-to-determine-level-of-code-coverage and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855605/maven-code-coverage-report-for-junit-test

Answer (score 2):

William - You may use JaCoCo, Cobertura or similar tools to get the code coverage. Even some IDE like IntelliJ IDEA has code coverage plugins